# jQuery form serializeObject

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with fields and a list of another object with items. But with jQuery `$("form").serializeObject()`, it is not creating the right object like here:

```
var functionViewModel = new Object();
functionViewModel.Id = 1;
functionViewModel.Name = "F-I-001";
functionViewModel.Localised = [];
functionViewModel.Localised.push({

  LocalisedId: '1|1',
  Subject: "F-N-001"
});

functionViewModel.CategoryViewModel = new Object();
functionViewModel.CategoryViewModel.CategoryInGroup = [];  
functionViewModel.CategoryViewModel.CategoryInGroup.push({
  Id: '1'
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution:

```
var myObj = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
};
var recEncoded = $.param( myObj);
var recDecoded = decodeURIComponent( $.param( myObj ) );

alert( recEncoded );
```

Comment: Yah but in this case I will still need to create the object and I would like the jquery to do  it by property name, property value etc

Answer (score 0):

Before sending data to server you need to `stringify()` the object. At the server you need to `parse()` it.

- Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert object to string. Use
- `JSON.parse()` to convert JSON object from string.

```js
var functionViewModel = new Object();
functionViewModel.Id = 1;
functionViewModel.Name = "F-I-001";
functionViewModel.Localised = [];
functionViewModel.Localised.push({

  LocalisedId: '1|1',
  Subject: "F-N-001"
});

functionViewModel.CategoryViewModel = new Object();
functionViewModel.CategoryViewModel.CategoryInGroup = [];  
functionViewModel.CategoryViewModel.CategoryInGroup.push({
  Id: '1'
})

var str = JSON.stringify(functionViewModel)
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(str);
console.log(obj);
```

To send it to server. Use

```
$.post(
  url: url, //Url of your server 
  data: JSON.stringify(obj), //data you want to send to server 
  function(data, status) {
    alert("Success");        
});
```

As pointed by Heena, you can use `param()`

You need to serialize/convert the object to a string before submitting it. You can use `$.param()` for this.

`$('#form').val($.param(functionViewModel));`

Comment: maybe I am expressing me wrong, I want jquery to read my page go field by field and create it for me

Comment: Try this `function objectifyForm(formArray) {//serialize data function

  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){
    returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }
  return returnArray;
}`