# Converting form data to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

I am building a search form, and I want to use JSON formatting of the search fields to call a generic web handler using AJAX.
My current challenge is this - I am using the following form code:

```
<form id="frmSearch" class="was-validated" method="post">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-1 text-end">Find companies where...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-start">
                    <select ID="ddlType" Class="form-control rounded" required>
                        <option value="" selected>Search by...</option>
                        <option value="company_name">Company Name</option>
                        <option value="city">City</option>
                        <option value="federal_ein">EIN</option>
                        <option value="state">State</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">contains...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex">
                    <input type="text" ID="tbTerm" class="form-control rounded text-black" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 mx-auto">
                    <input type="submit" ID="btnSearch" class="btn-success btn text-white" text="search" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Then, using an example I found here on SO, I am using jQuery to format the form fields to JSON, like so:

```
            $(function () {
                $('#frmSearch').submit(function () {
                    alert('got here');
                    var txt = JSON.stringify($('#frmSearch').serializeObject());
                    alert(txt)
                });
            })
```

The problem is, the alert triggers, so I know the code is executing, except the Stringify fails silently, and the second alert never triggers.  I don't get any errors in the console.  Any help here as to why this is happening?

Comment: It appears there is no (native) jQuery serializeObject. These links may shed light on your problem: [serializeobject](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/serializeobject), and [jquery-serializeobject-function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15277/jquery-serializeobject-function), and [jQuery form serializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554134/jquery-form-serializeobject), and [jsfiddle serializeobject](http://jsfiddle.net/7MAUv/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used jquery, nevertheless googling and with personal knowledge i came up with this.

```
 $(function () {
              $('#frmSearch').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                object= {}
                formData = new FormData(event.target);
                formData.forEach((value, key) => object[key] = value);
                alert('got here');
                var txt = JSON.stringify(object);
                alert(txt)
              })
 });
```

I hope i have been able to help you! Regards.

Comment: This doesn't work either.  The line 'FormData($(#frmSearch);' is missing a closing paren, plus the #frmSearch ,must be in single quotes.  Still the code doesn't work,  I get this error in the console: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.

Comment: I updated my comment based on your reply :D

Comment: I appreciate the update, but I still get nothing.  The return value in the 'txt' variable is '{}'.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: So, the solution is, your code works just fine.  The problem was, I didn't have name attributes on the form fields!  Thank you for the help.  Answer accepted.

Comment: Cannot work with multiple name input fields, tried return last one only.

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <form id="frmSearch" onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>...</form>
```

```js
     function onSubmit(form){
       var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() );
       alert( data );
       return false; //to test : prevent submiting
     }
```

Or using jquery:

```js
     $(function () {
        $('#frmSearch').submit(function () {
         var txt = JSON.stringify($('#frmSearch').serializeArray());
         alert(txt)
         });
     })
```

Comment: the call to the 'alert(txt)' returns '[]' as the value.  What is happening there?  I should see the JSON string, right?